# Can't start command line application with php using exec

Tags: php, exec, shell-exec

I'm trying to start a command line .exe application using php on a windows server with a WAMP stack:

```
<?php
exec("C:\\scraper\\Scraper.exe");
?>
```

Nothing happens on the server side and nothing is returned.

exec('whoami') works as does system("DIR");

Carmen

Comment: You could start by using exec()'s two other arguments to fetch some diagnose info.

Comment: Thanks your suggestion.
exec("C:\\scraper\\Scraper.exe", $output, $return); returns 255

Comment: If I echo $output[0]; I get an php error "undefined offset"

Comment: Don't use echo to debug, try at least var_dump(): `var_dump( exec("C:\\scraper\\Scraper.exe", $output, $return_var), $output, $return_var);`. It might also help to redirect STDERR to STDOUT.